# Use SELECT with field + variable in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i want to select value of field `id` from **Mysql** table `where` this `field` **+** php varibiable is between other two values.
I don't know why doesn't work.

```
$variable= 1;
$sin= 1;
$des= 3;

$query= "SELECT id AS id_ FROM users_table WHERE ((field + $variable) BETWEEN $sin AND $des) AND (otherfield = 1)";
```

Should works because `field == 1` **AND** `otherfield = 1`

```
field(1) + $variable(1) == 2 // so is between $sin and $des
```

**field** is *bigint(35)* and **othefield** is *Int(1)*

Please sorry my english, maybe is better to edit title

Comment: Your code and query seem correct. Can you post a printed query? I mean a result by ```print_r($query);```

Comment: @Borja did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert on MySQL, but from what I know, in the expression:

```sql
WHERE field BETWEEN a AND b
```

Field must be a column of the table rather than a value, because what you are comparing is the value of the column, not a number. What you should do is use the variable in your `BETWEEN` comparison. Something like:

```php
"SELECT id AS id_ FROM users_table WHERE field BETWEEN ".($sin + $variable)." AND ".($des - $variable)." AND otherfield = 1"
```

The end result after you PHP evaluates this expression would be something like:

```sql
SELECT id AS id_ FROM users_table WHERE field BETWEEN 5 AND 8 AND otherfield = 1
```

I am not sure exactly what your variables represent, but you should move your operation to the comparison part.

Answer (score 1):

You are using field + $variable it means a value in MySql Field must be a column of the table rather than a value.

```
SELECT id AS id_ FROM users_table WHERE column BETWEEN $sin + $variable AND $des - $variable AND othercolumn  = 1
```